# How do I ignore the tap if the user tapped on a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uibarbuttonitem

For some reason my UITapGestureRecognizer is blocking my toolbar buttons from being pressed when the recognizer is added to `self.view` and I don't want it to. In `shouldReceiveTouch` I want to return NO if the item is the toolbar button.

How do I do this, however? The items aren't UIBarButtonItems apparently, because when I put an if statement to check if `touch.view` is of that class, it ignores it. If I put a breakpoint there and inspect `touch.view` its class is `UIToolbarTextButton`. But `[UIToolbarTextButton class]` I get a "use of undeclared identifier UIToolbarTextButton" error.

Can I say if it's a subview of `UIToolBar`? What should I do?

Comment: Could you please show your code? I am able to use both tab gesture and bar button without any issue. Without seeing your code, it is difficult to provide a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, this is a hard question to answer... However it sounds like you are adding the Tapgesture recognizer to the same view as your toolbar... You could check the coordinates to see if they are within the CGrect of the uitoolbar... but really what I would recommend is creating a view which contains 2 subviews: one is your toolbar, the other is the main part of your view... then add the tapGesture only to the mainView. Good luck

Comment: When I create the so called mainView, how do I make it extend from the navigation bar to the toolbar at the bottom and maintain that distance for both 3.5 and 4 inch devices?

Comment: the easiest way to accomplish this is using a xib or storyboard. like i said you create two subviews. one for the Mainview and the other for your navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is not to add the UITapGestureRecognizer to the self.view.

Add a new view with Interface Builder that covers all the area but the toolbar area.

Put all your controls inside it and add the tap gesture to it.

Alternative: Add this to your ViewDidLoad function or somewhere you find more appropriate.

```
for (UIView *v in [toolbar items]) 
{
    v.tag = 5; // tag tool bar items
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    if (touch.view.tag == 5)
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: When I create the so called mainView, how do I make it extend from the navigation bar to the toolbar at the bottom and maintain that distance for both 3.5 and 4 inch devices?